# How to float div in CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have this list in HTML and I would like order it by columns. I tried using floats it gives me this:

**EDIT :** 
Height of these `<li>` is undefined, but I would like C below B, E below E and G below F without change the structure and change the order. I don't want to use position absolute. I'm wondering if there are other solutions.

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
   <li class="item">A</li>
   <li class="item">B</li>
   <li class="item">C</li>
   <li class="item">D</li>
   <li class="item">E</li>
   <li class="item">F</li>
   <li class="item">G</li>
<ul>
```

**OUTPUT** (using `float: left; width: 240px; border-left: 1px solid #EEE`) :

[image]

**What I want** is more like this below, **without changing the HTML** because I already use this structure to make responsive.

[image]

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you know width and/or height of boxes?

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what the rule is here - why is B not under A for example? Can you describe in words how the flow should go?

Comment: how about `float: right`? you would have to change your order of `li` maybe but not structure (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/68pKt/1/)). Though I tend to agree with the comment below.

Comment: That looks like it would be better laid out as a table.

Comment: Ok, saw your edit that you dont want to change the order. But what if you have a "H"? Where should it go?

Comment: @Harry No H :p, this is a structure very special

Comment: Can you use CSS3? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order Is the number of divs fixed? I don't quite understand the logic of the final layout you mentioned.

Comment: -1: `1` this should be 2 separate questions, one on how to style with columns, and one on how to have nothing under A; `2` the question would then be **much** better phrased as a generic question on how to style in columns (without the particularity of nothing under A); `3` you forgot to address @CupawnTae's comment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use column CSS and a margin-bottom on the first LI tag, [like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/trxLz).

```
ul {
     column-count:4;
     padding:0;
     column-rule: solid lightgray 1px;
}

li {
     display:inline-block;
     width:100%;
}

li:before {/* demo purpose to set an height to lis */
     content:'';
     float:left;
     padding-top:50%;
}

li:first-of-type {
     margin-bottom:50%;
}
```

You may need a JavaScript prefixer or add vendor-prefix manually.

Comment: Wow ! Crazy ! Exactly what I want. Is there a solution for IE8 ?

Comment: IE8, writing mode maybe, needs to be checked though, not using this rule very much since others starts to undeerstand it too.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai i understood he did not want H added to its special layout :)

Comment: ahhh..then it is perfect.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai you can remove the `li:first-of-type` rule and the layout seems to return to normal for an even number of elements. That makes this a *very* specialized layout - to support a variable number of items, you would have to use JS or server code to manipulate an inline-style on the first li - but brilliant none the less.

Comment: @PatrickM It can be addressed in CSS3 by selecting the first child only if it's odd when counting from the bottom (thus if there's an odd number of children) `li:first-child:nth-last-child(odd)` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cfvna (the trailing <ul> in GCyrillus's fiddle causes Firefox to create a shadow li or sth like that, must be corrected to `</ul>` or else the first of 7 children is even and not odd when counting from last to first...)